# load quickfixlist into a specific window

Tags: quickfix

I'm not interested in loading an item into a specific window. I'm interested in opening/loading quickfix list into a specific window/pane. Searched online everywhere, but couldn't find it. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

I don’t know of a built in way to do that, but here’s a function that will do it for you:

```
function! OpenQuickfixHere() abort
  copen
  let bufn = bufnr('%')
  let winn = winnr()
  wincmd p
  execute 'b'.bufn
  execute winn.'close'
endfunction
```

To use it, move the cursor to the window into which you would like to place the quickfix, and run the command:

```
:call OpenQuickfixHere()
```

You can of course map this or create a custom command for easier access.

It works by opening the quickfix (in a new window, as is standard), making a note of the buffer and window numbers, switching back to the original window, loading the quickfix buffer into that window, and then closing the original quickfix window.